# autofill (jQuery) not working with dynamic added rows in HTML Form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to autofill my PHP form by retrieving data from mysql table. It works fine on one row. The problem which I am facing is that when I dynamically add new rows using Javascript, then the auto fill does not work in dynamically created row. I want to knew how can I do autofill with dynamic created row

This is html markup:

```
<td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-end" name="scode[]" id="aaa"                    
           onkeyup="GetDetail(this.value)" value="">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-end" 
           name="servproname[]" id="bbb">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-end" name="qty[]"  
           id="ccc" >
</td>
```

This is the Javascript for add new row dynamically

```
function BtnAdd()
{
    /*Add Button*/
    var v = $("#TRow").clone().appendTo("#TBody");
    $(v).find("input").val('');
    $(v).removeClass("d-none");
    $(v).find("th").first().html($('#TBody tr').length - 1);
}
```

This is jQuery:

```
<script>
    // onkeyup event will occur when the user
    // release the key and calls the function
    // assigned to this event
    function GetDetail(str) {
        if (str.length == 0) {
            document.getElementById("bbb").value = "";
            document.getElementById("ccc").value = "";

            return;
        }
        else {
            // Creates a new XMLHttpRequest object
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

            // Defines a function to be called when
            // the readyState property changes
            if (this.readyState == 4 &&
                this.status == 200) {
                    
                // Typical action to be performed
                // when the document is ready
                var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                // Returns the response data as a
                // string and store this array in
                // a variable assign the value
                // received to first name input field
                
                document.getElementById("bbb").value = myObj[0];
                document.getElementById("ccc").value = myObj[1];
            }
       };

        // xhttp.open("GET", "filename", true);
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "gfg.php?user_id=" + str, true);
            
        // Sends the request to the server
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

This is php script

```
<?php

       // Get the user id
          $user_id = $_REQUEST['user_id'];

           // Database connection
            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "hmis");

            if ($user_id !== "") {

               // Get corresponding first name and
                 // last name for that user id  
                 $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT name, qty1 FROM machine1 WHERE user_id ='$user_id'");

                     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

            // Get the first name
                  $bbb = $row["name"];
              $ccc = $row["qty1"];
            }
               // Store it in a array
                  $result = array("$bbb", "$ccc");

                // Send in JSON encoded form
               $myJSON = json_encode($result);
            echo $myJSON;
          ?>
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Comment: You have two simple options, one is manually adding the entry with JavaScript when you submit the form.
The other more taxing is, right when the request is being send for adding, wait for the 200 and then re-request the search bar again. This will reload it with the new data (or should). But I would recommend the first option.

And as @Dharman said, PLEASE use parameterized queries to not enable SQL Injections!